# Can COMCTL32.OCX work on a 32 bit IE8 running on Win7 64bit?

Tags: internet-explorer-8, ocx, windows-7-x64

I have a legacy ASP web site that uses the treeview control from COMCTL32.OCX. It runs under XP 32 bit w/IE8 but it doesn't work under Win7 64 running either IE8 32 or 64. IE8 32 just shows blanks where the treeview should be and IE8 64 throws an error.

I have tried registering the OCX on the Win7 machine but get an error (I'll post the error # shortly).

Any clues or ideas?

TIA
J

Comment: Running the console as admin I was able to register the OCX but still not working in the web page.

Comment: Have you tried running IE with elevated rights as well?

Comment: Yes have tried running IE with elevated rights.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*I have tried registering the OCX on the Win7 machine but get an error*

If it's not registered you can not run it.

Try running regsvr32 under Dependency Walker (http://www.dependencywalker.com/) and check where and what the error is - this should give you the information as to what library is missing.

Answer (score 0):

I found that it was more advantages to rewrite the page using jquery to provide some very nice treeview functionality. I have abandoned the OCX efforts.